# How should I deploy PrimeFaces 3.5 into Glassfish 3.1.2?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish

When I deploy the jar file or Zip file it displays and error message saying there is no installed container capable of handling this application(I use admin console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primefaces is a JSF library, not an EAR/WAR/EJB-jar module. It is supposed to be deployed along with the application (i.e. within an EAR/WAR), not separately on the server. Include it in you application and it will available after deployment.

Comment: my default version is 3.4 how can I upgrade it to 3.5?

Comment: You can just replace the library reference in your IDE. For example in NetBeans, you can remove the reference from the project libraries, download the 3.5 jar and add a (jar) reference to that one.

Comment: Thanks but, Any way to make 3.5 as default?

Comment: This is IDE specific (plus it's irrelevant to the original question). You should start a new question tagged with your IDE...